# "heroku ps" shows no processes running

Tags: heroku

Seems like a simple question, but I haven't found the answer anywhere. Running `heroku ps` shows nothing. `heroku restart` executes successfully.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you tried scaling one of your process types? e.g. `heroku ps:scale web=1`

See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scaling

Comment: Simple answer to a simple problem.

Comment: Still would be nice to get _some_ sort of feedback from the command

Answer (score 0):

I was doing a silly mistake. I was using

heroku run ps (since there were other commands that I was using as "run")

instead of

heroku ps. (ps is a heroku command and not a system command).

Removing run fixed the issue. Thanks.